# Comparison between using VB.net or C# in ArcObjects or ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects, c#, vb.net

Is there any differences between using VB.net or C# in ArcObjects or ArcGIS Server based projects, in functionalities, samples, Q&A community? Is there any comparison which covers these aspects to help choose between them ?

Comment: This isn't a GIS question -- There is only one Esri library, so you're asking about Microsoft .Net implementation differences.

Comment: i'm asking about potiential differences towards using VB.net or C# with Arcgis serveror Arcobjects. this is not a generale comparaison between C# and VB.net

Comment: The question of the differences between two dot Net languages accessing one library is about the languages, not the library. That makes it off-topic, *and* subject to opinion-based commentary on the languages themselves.

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad because it is quite open-ended.  For example, just one of your questions "Is there any differences between using VB.net or C# in ArcObjects or ArcGIS Server based projects, in ... samples ...?" could potentially yield many answers, and be too broad in its own right.  If you are trying to choose which you should use then I think you should ask about a requirement that you are trying to meet that your leading candidate language appears not to meet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference at all. You can start developing with any of those languages that your are more comfortable with. As @Vince has mentioned in the comments, there is one ArcObjects library.

All of the samples are available in both languages. e.g. see [here](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/sdk/10.0/ArcObjects_NET/componenthelp/index.html#//0048000001q6000000)

Comment: Evidenced by there being only one ArcObjects help, with implementations given in 3 languages. There are subtle differences in implementation for example in VB with IPointCollection.AddPoint the before/after arguments can be omitted but in C# this will cause a compile error and need to be Type.Missing.